# MySQL select the count of a number range

Tags: mysql

I am not certain how to do this select. Here is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `step` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

The step column will contain an integer between 0 and 7. I am attempting to count how many records I have in my table for the range of steps 1 through 6. I need the entire range (1 - 6) including where COUNT equals zero. I would like it to return in order -- something like this.

```
+----------+----------+
|   step   |     n    |
+----------+----------+
|   Step 1 |     100  |
+----------+----------+
|   Step 2 |     150  |
+----------+----------+
|   Step 3 |     135  |
+----------+----------+
```

I was hoping I would not need to define a procedure for this. Is there a simple way of getting what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    s.step
  , COALESCE(t.n, 0) AS n
FROM
        ( SELECT 1 AS step UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 UNION ALL
          SELECT 4 UNION ALL
          SELECT 5 UNION ALL
          SELECT 6 
        ) AS s
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT step 
               , COUNT(*) AS n 
          FROM my_table 
          GROUP BY step 
        ) AS t
      ON t.step = s.step
ORDER BY
    s.step ;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS s     LEFT JOIN         ( SELECT step, COUNT(*) AS n            FROM my_table' at line 10

Comment: Brilliant. This did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler if you just created a table listing all the valid steps, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE steps (
  step int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO steps VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
```

Then you can do a `LEFT JOIN` against it to get the record counts ([SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/o6N0UE9avy)):

```
SELECT
  step, COUNT(id) AS n 
FROM
  steps LEFT JOIN my_table USING (step) 
GROUP BY step;
```

The important part is `COUNT(id)`: that only counts rows where the `id` column is not null.  Since `id` is defined as a non-null column, that means it only discounts the dummy rows created by the left join for steps that would otherwise have no records.

Of course, if you really didn't want to create a real table (or even a temporary one), you could also do this with ypercube's `UNION ALL` subselect trick ([SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/ptE1W7t05v)):

```
SELECT step, COUNT(id) AS n
FROM 
  ( SELECT 1 AS step UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 
  ) AS steps
LEFT JOIN my_table USING (step)
GROUP BY step;
```

Comment: I consider it poor form to create a new table in my database for an array of data that is unlikely to change in both quantity and value. At this point, I am essentially creating a table to make a select work on another table rather than using tables to house data. To me, that indicates there is something wrong with my approach. Your follow-up suggestion is very close to ypercube's. Ypercube selected my table within a derived table select and you didn't. I am unable to determine which approach is the wiser for my purposes.

Comment: Well, you could always make it a temporary table, created just for that query.

Comment: It isn't necessary now. The queries you both gave me provide the result I need without having to mess with additional tables or procedures of any kind. Thanks. :)